# How do you set a username / password on a WCF Client using configuration?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-client, ws-security

I know I can do this through code using

```
myClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "User";
myClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Password";
```

Is it possible to provide the same thing for a client through configuration instead?

Comment: No, this is one of the few settings that can be set **only** in code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible.  However, you can manually read your .config file settings and set it programmatically...

```
clientCredentials.UserName.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"];
clientCredentials.UserName.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible out of the box. More importantly it wouldn't be very secure either.

Anyone who has access to the config file would then have the credentials for the service. For a client application, this will be anyone who can run the program as they will have read access to the application install location.

Comment: If you can store credentials for your database connection in the config, why not for the service?  I agree that it may not be the most secure method, but it would, however, follow suit with other such patterns already practiced.

Comment: Just because you can doesn't make it a good idea :) Sometimes databases have to use sql authentication, but that still makes it less secure than using integrated authentication for the database connection.

Comment: I recently got around this issue by p/invoking the CredRead and CredWrite Win32 api calls. I then logged into the server using the service account and added the required credentials to Windows Credential Manager. This is where Windows is able to encrypt and store generic credentials.

The service then resolve the credentials at runtime and used them to authenticate against the remote service.

This method allowed ensured the protection of the credentials from being written to disk in plain text and also allowed the application to use username/password authentication.